# Format specifier for hex char in C

Tags: c, hex, format-specifiers

Is there a format specifier for `sprintf` in C that maps a `char` to hex in the same way that `%x` maps an `int` to hex?

Comment: what do you mean map a char to hex? sprintf formats strings with integral values, a char is just an integral value so if you mean the hex of the decimal value behind a char then just use `%x`

Comment: @DanZimm I guess I just want it to display 1 byte of hex rather than 4 bytes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes and no.

Since `sprintf` takes a variable argument list, all arguments undergo default promotion before `sprintf` receives them. That means `sprintf` will *never* receive a `char` -- a `char` will always be promoted to `int` before `sprintf` receives it (and a `short` will as well).

Yes, since what `sprintf` is receiving will be an `int`, you can use `%x` to convert it to hex format, and it'll work the same whether that value started as a `char`, `short`, or `int`. If (as is often the case) you want to print 2 characters for each input, you can use `%2.2x`.

Beware one point though: if your `char` is signed, and you start with a negative value, the promotion to `int` will produce the same numerical value, which normally *won't* be the same bit pattern as the original char, so (for example) a char with the value `-1` will normally print out as `ffff` if `int` is 16 bits, `ffffffff` if int is 32 bits, or `ffffffffffffffff` if `int` is 64 bits (assuming the typical 2's complement representation for signed integers).

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 7):

That's the same `%x`. All `char` values are converted to `int` before being passed to `sprintf` (or any other function that takes variable number of parameters).

```
printf("%x\n", 'a');
```

prints `61`

Comment: `printf(%x\n", (char)0x90);` prints `ffffff90`, when I want it to print `90`

Comment: I also want `printf(%x\n, (char)1)` to print `01` instead of `1`.

Comment: @Daniel use `%02x` to force zero-padding two-character output.

Comment: @Daniel Casting `0x90` to `unsigned char` instead of `char` will fix the sign extension problem.